# when browser is waiting

Tags: java, sockets, browser, http-headers

I have java program that read request headers from browser (with HTTP proxy) and then respond it.
How can my program understand browser is waiting for respond without close connection.
I understand when browser is waiting he send ""(I don't know what is it!) in end of header . but it's not null and when i check it it doesn't work.
see code below:

```
message = reader.readLine();
while (!((message == null) || (message == ""))) {
    message = reader.readLine();
}
client.close();
```

But here it doesn't get out of while for `!(message == "")`

Header:

```
GET http://localhost/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
(waiting for respond)
null (for closing connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

In java, you compare strings with `equals`:

```
message.equals("")
```

Comment: Yip `(message == "")` will return false ... even when `message` is an empty string `""`.